# Android Lifecycle View.setOnClickListener

Tags: android, events, android-lifecycle

Now for the Question all this is not really that important but I just like to have a framework to talk about.

Lets say we have an activity as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

now assume we have a button and we bind to it's click event like so

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

If you need to unbind you could do it like so

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(null);
```

**Question:** In the android life-cycle in witch events do you bind/unbind/rebind if you even need to unbind in the first place.

Comment: there is no need to "unbound" from the onClickListener. Still as general rule you can always register inside the onResume and unbound inside the onPause

Comment: Thanks I can't accept you comment can I?

Comment: Ok so then I'm to understand that the member variables exist as long as the android OS has not Destroyed the Activity in which case I would get the onDestroy event. Thus no need to unbind or rebind since the framework will keep my member variable's populated even after a stop event?